# Lazy loading - what's the best approach?

Tags: c#, architecture, coding-style, lazy-loading, methodology

I have seen numerous examples of lazy loading - what's your choice?

Given a model class for example:

```
public class Person
{
    private IList<Child> _children;
    public IList<Child> Children
    {
        get {
            if (_children == null)
                LoadChildren();
            return _children;
        }
    }
}
```

The Person class should not know anything about how it's children are loaded .... or should it? Surely it should control when properties are populated, or not?

Would you have a repository that couples a Person together with its children collection or would you use a different approach, such as using a [lazyload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375881/lazy-loading-and-lazy-execution-patterns) class - even then, I don't want a lazyload class blurring in my model architecture.

How would you handle performance if first requesting a Person and then its Children (i.e. not lazy loading in this instance) or somehow lazy loading.

Does all this boil down to personal choice?

Comment: Problem - this is quite often a great example of local optimization at the expense of global optimization.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best lazy loading is avoiding it ;) Thread safety is an immediate problem you'll have to handle. I have no count of how often I have seen production systems with 8 cpu cores run lazy loading 8 times for *every single* lazy loading pattern in use. At least on server startups all server cores have a tendency to end up in the same places.

Let a DI framework construct it for you instead, if you can. And if you cannot, I still prefer explicit construction. So all sorts of AOP magic simply do not cut it with me, go for explicit construction outside the class. Don't put it inside the person class, just make a service that constructs the objects in the proper manner.

Introducing "magic" layers that more or less transparently do these things *seem* like a nice idea, but I have yet to come across implementations that do not have unforseen and problematic consequences.

Comment: Thanks for your time, can you elaborate on using a DI framework and explicit construction?

Comment: I think he was saying that having the Person class explicitly create the children (with LoadChildren() presumably) during its own initialization leaves no doubt as to the state of _children.  And Dependency Injection, well there are many threads here that're better than me in a comment.

Comment: Also - you lose the atomicity of the query. And more often than not the most efficient overall strategy is to issue a single query with (outer?) joins for the child records and get everything in one transaction, rather than spreading it out across multiple database sub-hits.

Comment: @Tim I was a little out-of-order in my post; try to make a service that constructs the whole structure you require - that is explicit construction. Don't try to hide object construction, just do it in the right place. DI construction is a different ballgame and may be less optimal for domain objects

Comment: @Krosenvold - no offence taken ;) - I too don't like the "magic" layers. They confuse the situation in my eyes. So your approach would be similar to @Toran below?

Comment: @Le Dorfier - Agree with performance concerns. There comes a tipping point though when an object may have too many child relationships to warrant loading everything at once. What do you do in these situations?

Comment: I would also like to know what to do in the "too many child relationships" situation

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Lazy<T>` class I talked about here :
[What is the proper way to inject a data access dependency for lazy loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130292/what-is-the-proper-way-to-inject-a-data-access-dependency-for-lazy-loading/522547#522547)

There is also link to a more detailed blog post there...

Answer (score 1):

I talked about a solution I use to accomplish lazy loading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130292/what-is-the-proper-way-to-inject-a-data-access-dependency-for-lazy-loading/131059#131059)

Comment: Thanks for your time, is this not just another dependency though? I am interested in the approach though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Virtual Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading#Virtual_proxy) pattern, along with the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). This would give you lazy loading without the Person class having explicit knowledge about how Children are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that this is *precisely* the kind of problem that is best handled by AOP (e.g., PostSharp). Have your lazy loading as an aspect and then use it to decorate whatever property you want to be loaded lazily. Disclaimer: haven't tried it; just thinking that it *should* work.

Answer (score 0):

I just asked a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652195/is-a-lock-required-with-a-lazy-initialization-on-a-deeply-immutable-type), but it was heavier on the Immutability & Thread Safety tack.  Lots of good answers and comments.  You may find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example implementing lazy loading using the Proxy pattern

The Person class that would live with the rest of your models. Children is marked as virtual so it can be overridden inside the PersonProxy class.

```
public class Person {
    public int Id;
    public virtual IList<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

The PersonRepository class that would live with the rest of your repositories. I included the method to get the children in this class but you could have it in a ChildRepository class if you wanted.

```
public class PersonRepository {
    public Person FindById(int id) {
        // Notice we are creating PersonProxy and not Person
        Person person = new PersonProxy();

        // Set person properties based on data from the database

        return person;
    }

    public IList<Child> GetChildrenForPerson(int personId) {
        // Return your list of children from the database
    }
}
```

The PersonProxy class that lives with your repositories. This inherits from Person and will do the lazy loading. You could also use a boolean to check if it has already been loaded instead of checking to see if Children == null.

```
public class PersonProxy : Person {
    private PersonRepository _personRepository = new PersonRepository();

    public override IList<Child> Children {
        get {
            if (base.Children == null)
                base.Children = _personRepository.GetChildrenForPerson(this.Id);

            return base.Children;
        }
        set { base.Children = value; }
    }
}
```

You could use it like so

```
Person person = new PersonRepository().FindById(1);
Console.WriteLine(person.Children.Count);
```

Of course you could have PersonProxy take in an interface to the PersonRepository and access it all through a service if you don't want to call the PersonRepository directly.